# Show calculated arithmetic mean in <td> when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

please help me finish this, I'm getting nowhere.

[what needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCjI.jpg)
[final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2CbH.jpg)

I've explained in the pictures whats the finish goal.
This is a grade calculator.

There are 3 types of grades.. it should calculate the arithmetic mean for every category and arithmetic mean for all grades no matter which category they are.

Calculated values should be shown on the appropriate block, as shown in the picture.

````
input[type="number"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="number"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="stranica" style="display: inline-block; position: left;">
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:dodajocenu();"> Add grade</button>
</div>

<div id="desna" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; text-align: center;">

<button type="button" onclick=""> Calculate </button>
<br><br>
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Written test</td>
<td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Essay</td>
<td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Class Activity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td> <!-- insert arithmetic mean of all Writtentest, inside td-->
<td style="text-align: center;"></td> <!-- insert arithmetic mean of all Essay, inside td-->
<td style="text-align: center;"></td> <!-- insert arithmetic mean of all ClassActivity, inside td-->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:140px; text-align: center;">Arithmetic mean of all grades</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td> <!-- insert arithmetic mean of all numbers-->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var ocena = 0;

var stranica = document.querySelector("#stranica")

function removeElement(obrisi) {
  var dugme = obrisi.target;
  stranica.removeChild(dugme.parentElement)
}

function dodajocenu() {
  ocena++;

  //create textbox
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "number";
  input.setAttribute("max",5);
  input.setAttribute("min",1);

  var myParent = document.body;

  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["Written test","Essay","Class Activity"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement('select');
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  myParent.appendChild(selectList);

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }   

  //create remove button
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.onclick = function(obrisiocenu) {
    removeElement(obrisiocenu);
  }
  remove.setAttribute("type", "dugme");
  remove.innerHTML = "-"; //delete 

  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.classList.add("item")

  item.appendChild(input);
  item.appendChild(selectList);
  item.appendChild(remove);

  stranica.appendChild(item)
}
</script>```
````

Comment: give it a try on mean computing code, can you just translate some key word in english ?

Comment: I changed some text, hope it helps.

Comment: It seems you have done nothing yet in order to calculate the mean. This sounds like homework, so please refer to what you have learned and apply it. When you have a specific problem in that implementation, then at least show the code that attempts to implement the solution. The JS code you provided is about adding a grade. There is nothing about the mean-calculation.

Comment: Not homework, but personal project. We have not even started JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ocena = 0;

function removeElement(obrisi) {
  var dugme = obrisi.target;
  document.getElementById("stranica").removeChild(dugme.parentElement)
}

function dodajocenu() {
  ocena++;

  //create textbox
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "number";
  input.setAttribute("max", 5);
  input.setAttribute("min", 1);

  var myParent = document.body;

  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["Kontrolni", "Vezbe", "Aktivnost"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement('select');
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  myParent.appendChild(selectList);

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //create remove button
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.onclick = function(obrisiocenu) {
    removeElement(obrisiocenu);
  }
  remove.setAttribute("type", "dugme");
  remove.innerHTML = "-"; //delete 

  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.classList.add("item")

  item.appendChild(input);
  item.appendChild(selectList);
  item.appendChild(remove);

  document.getElementById("stranica").appendChild(item)
}
function calcMean() {

var nameList=document.querySelectorAll('#stranica .item #mySelect');
var inputList=document.querySelectorAll('#stranica .item input');
var kontrolniList = [];
var vezbeList = [];
var aktivnostList = [];
var ocenaList = [];
for(var i=0; i< nameList.length; i++){
    ocenaList.push(parseInt(inputList[i].value));
    if(nameList[i].value=='Kontrolni') {
        kontrolniList.push(parseInt(inputList[i].value));
    }
    else if(nameList[i].value=='Vezbe') {
        vezbeList.push(parseInt(inputList[i].value));
    }
    else if(nameList[i].value=='Aktivnost') {
        aktivnostList.push(parseInt(inputList[i].value));
    }
}
    document.getElementById("kontrolni").innerHTML=avg(kontrolniList);
    document.getElementById("vezbe").innerHTML=avg(vezbeList);
    document.getElementById("aktivnost").innerHTML=avg(aktivnostList);
    document.getElementById("ocena").innerHTML=avg(ocenaList);
}
function avg( arr ) {
var total = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total / arr.length;
}
```

```html
<div id="stranica" style="display: inline-block; position: left;">
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:dodajocenu();"> Dodaj ocenu</button>
</div>

<div id="desna" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; text-align: center;">

  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:calcMean();"> Izracunaj prosek</button>
  <br><br>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Kontrolni</td>
        <td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Vezbe</td>
        <td style="width:70px; text-align: center;">Aktivnost</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="kontrolni" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="vezbe" style="text-align: center;"></td>
        <td id="aktivnost" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:140px; text-align: center;">Zakljucna ocena</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ocena" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this will work.